# RxJS: How to emit the event that takeWhile evaluates to false for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
const kickstart$ = curry((pred, iStream, hStream) =>
    iStream()
    .pipe(
        take(1),
        flatMap(({processId: pid}) => poller$(hStream(pid))),
        takeWhile(pred),
        catchError(x => of(x))
    )
)
```

The `takeWhile` statement is there to stop the stream once the `pred` function returns false. The problem is, I *also* want those final values to be emitted so that the subscriber can know what the final state of the stream was, which contains information like `status: stopped` or `status: error`, but then I want it to end after that.

If I only check for `status !== "stopped" || status !== "error"` in my `takeWhile`, then that final event will not get emitted.

How do I also include that final event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which `rxjs` version do you use?

There already is a takeWhile overload with a boolean flag for `inclusive last`.

```
takeWhile(pred, true)
```

If you're using older versions you will have to do something else like concating the last emited value after `takeWhile`

I believe inclusive last was added in 6.4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using 6.5.1, so this works for me. Strangely, I did not see this documented in [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takewhile.html) or [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile). Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know, I just posted a merge request for https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takewhile.html :)

Comment: Oh, there it is already!